# No polkit authentication agent found vs code

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

> Failed to save 'file.py' :
> Insufficient permissions.

i get this prompt whenever i try to save a file in my vs code. I am told to try again as a super use which i do but it says

> No Polkit authentication agent found

im not sure what is that supposed to mean any help?

`os : Ubuntu22.04`

`de : gnome`

`wm : bspwm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing `lxpolkit` and running the program in the terminal. When it tried to save again as root, from vscodium in my case, I was prompted for my password and was able to save.

Comment: To be clear, the exact procedure is: (1) install `lxpolkit` i.e. `sudo apt install lxpolkit` or similar, (2) open a terminal and **run `lxpolkit`**. It will hang, nothing will appear to happen. **Keep the terminal open.** (3) with the terminal open, run vscode and try saving something as root. It should work.